# Display user online script

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code:

```
    $user_query = executeQuery("SELECT * 
                                FROM student 
                                WHERE stdid=".$_SESSION['stdid'].";")
                  or die(mysql_error());

    $row =  mysql_fetch_array($user_query);

    $user_query1 = executeQuery("SELECT * 
                                 FROM testconductor 
                                 WHERE tcid=".$_SESSION['tcid'].";")
                   or die(mysql_error());

    $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($user_query1);

    $vst_id = '-Vizitator-';         

    $uvon = isset($_SESSION['stdname'])
            ?  ($row['nume_student']." ".$row['prenume_student']) 
            : $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']. $vst_id ;

    $uvon = isset($_SESSION['tcname']) 
            ?  $row1['nume_profesor']." ".$row1['prenume_profesor'] 
            : $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']. $vst_id;
```

How can i join both `$uvon` in one to display correct users from both database tables if they login ?

Now with this code it's displaying only `$uvon` with `tcname` and first `$uvon` display `stdname` as Guest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, plz consider 2 things :

- Think about mysqli or PDO - Because mysql functions are depreciated
- Bad indentation isn't cool to read.

Let's walkthrough the $uvon variables (to highlight overwrite problems)

```
$uvon = isset($_SESSION['stdname'])
        ?  ($row['nume_student'] . " " . $row['prenume_student']) 
        : $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] . $vst_id ;

$uvon = isset($_SESSION['tcname']) 
        ?  $row1['nume_profesor'] . " " . $row1['prenume_profesor'] 
        : $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] . $vst_id;
```

Case  :
**Student case**

- **1st declaration of $uvon**
  `isset($_SESSION['stdname']) == TRUE`

  ```
  $uvon = ($row['nume_student'] . " " . $row['prenume_student'])
  ```
- **2nd declaration of $uvon** : `isset($_SESSION['tcname'] == FALSE`

  ```
  $uvon = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] . $vst_id i.e. ('-Vizitator-')
  ```

To fix it :

Use If/else statement instead `Mark?Colon:` 
(I suppose it is possible with `Mark?Colon`: but would be unreadable).

**Code :**

```
if(isset($_SESSION['stdname']))
   $uvon = ($row['nume_student'] . " " . $row['prenume_student']);

elseif(isset($_SESSION['tcname']))
   $uvon = $row1['nume_profesor'] . " " . $row1['prenume_profesor'];

else
   $uvon = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] . $vst_id;
```

Comment: Anytime. If this is the solution you use, feel free to accept it by clicking the checkmark next to the answer so future readers know what solved your problem.